# Storm drpc server does not accept spout request

Tags: apache-storm

I am using apache storm 0.9.3 in Ubuntu 14.04. I put zookeeper, nimubus, drpc,supervisor, ui, worker in same box. From ui, it lookes fine:

[image: Topology picture]
[image: spout]

I have storm.yaml configureation as follows:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "localhost"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
nimbus.host: "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "/var/stormtmp"
java.library.path: "/usr/local/lib"

supervisor.slots.ports:
   -6700
   -6701
   -6702
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
drpc.servers:
   - "localhost"
```

Then, my java client DRPC call as follows: "callstatio" is the topology name in storm UI.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TException, DRPCExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Entering main in TestSpout");
        String host = "127.0.0.1";      
        DRPCClient client = new DRPCClient(host, 3772);
        System.out.println("host is:"+host);
        String result = client.execute("callstatio","hello world");
        System.out.println("result is:"+result);
        }
```

When I run the Client:

I could not see any request happens in drpc.log, neither there is exception.
Any hints why I could not get drpc server working?

The following is from tail -f drpc.log

```
2015-03-25T03:50:56.842-0400 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.home=/root
2015-03-25T03:50:56.842-0400 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.dir=/home/juhani/storm/apache-storm-0.9.3/bin
2015-03-25T03:50:57.293-0400 b.s.d.drpc [INFO] Starting Distributed RPC servers...
2015-03-25T04:09:27.331-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 1 start at 1427270366
2015-03-25T04:11:22.337-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 2 start at 1427270477
2015-03-25T04:13:42.342-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 3 start at 1427270620
2015-03-25T04:16:32.349-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 4 start at 1427270791
2015-03-25T04:20:52.358-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 5 start at 1427271047
2015-03-25T04:23:07.373-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 6 start at 1427271183
2015-03-25T04:25:27.377-0400 b.s.d.drpc [WARN] Timeout DRPC request id: 7 start at 1427271325
```

Comment: I did not continue to trouble shooting. I use nodejs->kafka->storm->mongodb, with that tool chain, everything is smooth.

Comment: sorry for lata reply, i'm still new to storm do you mean you are now using update version of storm ?

Comment: i'm facing same problem but didn't fix it , i imported project that it's supposed to work well but got same error  , do you have any information about this ?

Comment: are you still here ?

Comment: where is this line cluster.submitTopology("drpc-demo", conf, builder.createRemoteTopology()); in your code  ?

Comment: @user5520049 I finally using Kafka, then Storm. Then there is no this problem. Kafka spout know how to connect storm.

Comment: @user84592 thanks for replying